# Separated, but combined polygons - unable to split. What determines that?

Tags: qgis, splitting

In Mapinfo it works well when splitting polygons if they are physically separated(non-combined). However, occasionally when conducting "multiparts to singleparts" in QGIS, some errors occur, although the majority of the polygons are processed correct. The logic behind the task must be that polygons that don´t intersects can be splitted. Or?

Comment: Add a screen capture of such case and if possible WKT of such polygon so that others can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: I will try out out your suggestions and return with an update.

Comment: Awesome, buddy! Glad you got the results you wanted. Sure, will post the above comment as an answer for the convenience of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Multipart Split** plugin which should give you the results you want.

For some additional information, the [quote](http://djjr-courses.wikidot.com/soc128:qgis-parts) below gives a brief description of what Multiparts to singleparts does.

> "This function will convert a multipart polygon with the same object ID to multiple singlepart polygons. This will separate all polygons even if non-contiguous. This has the ability to create simple polygons and lines from the multipart polygon."